# Kendo Treelist imageClass not supported anymore

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, icons, kendo-treelist

I need the new equivalent for `imageClass` for TreeLIST or any other possibility to add an icon to an treelist TOOLBAR button

Comment: What do you mean with *not supported anymore*? It still in [its docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/configuration/toolbar#toolbar.imageClass).

Comment: @DontWoteMeDown unfortunately, the docs are outdated

Answer (score 0):

The [`toolbar`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/configuration/toolbar#toolbar) accepts a template so you can customize your whole toolbar. The negative part is that you need to write the whole HTML for each button and handle all its events as well. Still, it is an alternative. Example:

```js
  $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
    toolbar: '<button type="button" data-command="custom" class="k-button k-button-icontext about-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-info"></span>About</button>',
    columns: [
      "lastName",
      "position"
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { id: 1, parentId: null, lastName: "Jackson", position: "CEO" },
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, lastName: "Weber", position: "  VP, Engineering" }
    ]
  });
  
  $("#treeList").on("click", "button.about-button", function() {
    console.log("About button clicked");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script><script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
    
<div id="treeList"></div>
```

Comment: I copied this code and still haven't any icon. Also, the toolbar does not appear on top of the list (the column headings appear on top and the toolbar is located under them).